# Ways to work around a memory leak in Java

Tags: java

I'm building a large import script that uses functionality from a separate code base that I suspect of having a memory leak.  It calls the code base as many as 10000 times for the same operations and while the first is relatively quick (2 sec) the script is requiring a long time to run (over 100 hours and counting) and by the end the same task is up to 60 sec or more (and still climbing).  What is the best way to work around this while the leaks are found and fixed?

Some solutions that have been brainstormed would be:

Create a process that runs a part of the script then end it, reclaiming the resources it used.

Use a shell script to launch the program multiple times completing a sub-set of the tasks each time and have the updated data output to file to be used by the next iteration

edit: Changed the way the question was phrased to make it clear that the import and the code base are separate programs

Comment: Hire someone else to find and fix the leaks. Add lots of memory to the machine.

Comment: Memory solution has been tried, it no longer generates out of memory but the script requires far too long to run, looking like it may take longer than a week at the current rate.

Comment: if it's possible to split the import up, I'd do that. It's quick and simple. But you have to be sure that every line of the import is stand-alone and no references to earlier import lines are required.

Comment: **Make** the time to fix the memory leaks.

Comment: I would have thought that in the 100 hours it takes to run you would get time to find the memory leaks. Failing that, yes, split the file into sections to speed it up for now until it fails sometime later due to the same memory leaks

Comment: Without determining the actual problem, your work around might not help or could make it worse.

Comment: Fixing the leaks will be done regardless, however my question was related to the best way to work around it while the leaks are being fixed.  (Updated question to indicate the leaks WILL be fixed)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this issue by minimizing the scope that contains references to the other codebase. Basically every time I initialize an object or call a function from the other codebase I went through hoops to make sure it existed for the minimal time possible. Often setting references again to NULL in order to make sure all references were removed.

This ended up working excellently, reduced the time from over 150 hours and counting to under 30.

Answer (score 2):

You know, none of the evidence you have presented clearly points to a storage leak.  The real problem could be something completely different, like a poorly designed algorithm, or a poorly tuned database table or query.

Assuming that this is a storage leak and applying "band-aid" solutions could be a waste of time, or actually make the problem worse.

You will be better off spending the time up front to determine what the real problem is and fix it, rather than trying a series of workarounds ... which may turn out to be futile.

Comment: Yeah, that makes a lot of sense, I agree, don't have the option though, my assignment is to find a way to make it work.  The script will only be run once so the time isn't available for me to follow your excellent advice, which is why I'm asking for help with the workarounds.

Comment: @FooBar - Well good luck.  I doubt that we'll be able to suggest any workarounds that have much chance of working.